# move svn repository from Linux to Windows

Tags: svn, repository

I have done alot of research on this and thought it would be a easy task, but guess I was wrong.  I will outline everything I did to move the svn repository, but am not able to relocate, or checkout the directories.

Linux config =

```
svn in /home/services/svn/asr
checkout would be svn://"server name"/asr
performed svnadmin dump /home/services/svn/asr > asr.dump
```

Everything here worked fine, and I moved the 25GB dump to the Windows server

Windows config =

```
created a new repository (svnadmin create c:\svn\asr)
performed svnadmin load c:\svn\asr < asr.dump
everything loaded fine to revision 538 (which is head revision)
created a service to run svnserve.exe with --root c:\svn\asr
added my passwd, authz, and setup everything
```

When attempting to relocate I get a error about not being the root of the repository.  I am using svn://"server name"/asr

If I create a new folder and perform a checkout from svn"//"server name"/asr I get a error stating:

Comment: You get an error stating what? I'm waiting with bated breath. BTW, did you use a tool to do the dump and load, or did you do it manually? It's sort of hard figuring it out from the format of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem could be with the configuration of the service rather than the integrity of the repository.

The first thing to try is whether you can do `svnlook` operations from a command prompt on the server, eg `svnlook log c:\svn\asr` .  If that's fine then it suggests the repository is ok.  The setup of svnserve with the root of c:\svn\asr looks ok at first glance, but you could try running the service in the foreground, which may give you more information:

```
runas /user:whatever_your_svn_service_user_is_called cmd
(opens a new command window running as the SVN service user)
svnserve -X --foreground --root c:\svn\asr
```

and now try doing a checkout again.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the dump, but the configuration of your server:
You have to start server via

```
svnserve.exe -d  --root c:\svn\
```

(without the reponame) Then you can checkout or relocate via URL

```
svn://<Servername>/asr
```

Otherwise you have stated the asr twice (first in svnserve, second in URL) and this is not an existing repository(would be c:\svn\asr\asr ..).

BTW: If you used FSFS Repositories(standard setting since SVN 1.3, I think) You just can file copy the repository without dump/reload. Dump/reload cycles are really slow and dumps are very bloated